# Unable to install Eclipse, "Failed to create Java Virtual Machine." error

Tags: eclipse, jvm

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
128M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
128m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7.0_45
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
-XX:MaxPermSize=256M
```

System Specification:
Processor:Intel(R)Core(TM)i5 CPU  M450 @ 2.40 GHz
RAM:3GB
System Type: 32 bit

Comment: You should install JDK before eclipse. Also if you are trying to use eclipse for android development, use eclipse SDK especially for android. You won't need to install ADT bundle separately.

Comment: To install eclipse you only need Java installed on your pc, uncompress the zip that you download from eclipse web page into any folder and start eclipse.exe. This error when is showed up? Could you give more info?

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you are following these steps.

1) Install jdk(1.6 or 1.7) and set the path in enviornment variables.

2) Download android SDK ADT bundle from Android developers site.

3) Thats all you need to do basically.

Now, if you are getting "Failed to create the java virtual machine".

```
What you have to do is, edit your eclipse.ini file. Which is there in eclipse 
folder.

And write the following line in eclipse.ini file.

-startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar


-vm
 C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_29\bin\javaw.exe 


--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 128M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
128m
--launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 -vmargs
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7.0_45
 -Xms40m
 -Xmx768m
 -Declipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
 -XX:MaxPermSize=256M


 Imp Note: Replace  **C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_29\bin\javaw.exe** with your path.
```